# how do I split string equation into its own array of strings?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I Evaluate a certain formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522178/how-would-i-evaluate-a-certain-formula)

How would I split this formula into an array of characters each having their own number in the array:

```
a1+a2+a5*((a1+a6)*a3)
```

one I have added the spaces I am going to get column 1 because a1 will indicate column one and it will contain a number than I will add that to column 2. I am not allowed to use a tree or any of those other things just stacks and I have been asking that. But people keep telling me to use libraries and trees I am only in a 200 level course !

Comment: This is not an equation. :) Also, what is the desired result exactly?

Comment: a1 + a2 + a5 * ( ( a1 + a6 ) * a3 )

Comment: That's just another string. In fact, the same string, but with more spaces. What does the array you desire look like?

Comment: if you could help me do the spacing I know I can do the array part :)

Comment: The answers will be the [same as they were yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522178/how-would-i-evaluate-a-certain-formula). Are you having a problem (a) creating a parser, as most people suggested, or (b) integrating an existing EL and using a custom resolver, as I suggested?

Comment: @ashley, In this particular case, you could use a regular expression to insert spaces before and after each group of letters-and-numbers. Not sure if that would be generic enough though.

Comment: also if you're trying to parse the expression, you'll have to use something like expression tree.

Comment: (Oh, I misunderstood--if you just want to put spaces around operators, a regex and replace would be an easy way to do it. Sorry!)

Comment: @ashleysmith No offense, but it looks like you are asking a "bad question." I believe that your question is in good faith, but I don't think that the answer to your question is the best progress toward your larger goal. I recommend you explain your larger goal and how you see your question leading toward that goal.

Comment: no I am going to take each one and push and pop them onto a stack :)

Comment: Agreed, what do you want your results to look like.  Also, depending on what you want to use it for, the parenthesis may cause problems - I think the general method I've seen for constructing equation graphs is to use a binary tree structure (where the parenthesis end up disappearing).

Comment: @ashley, Pushing each array element onto the stack (whatever that means) won't work. Explain your larger purpose instead.

Comment: I believe we're playing "the telephone game" - ashley smith's teacher probably asked him to implement something like this - http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/index.htm

Comment: Kevin D ? He ? why are u saying HE ?

Comment: @ashley smith - Sorry - I shouldn't have assumed your gender. (In my defense, "Ashley" is a unisex name - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashley_%28name%29)

Comment: Ah this time of the year again. We really need some way to hide all those CS101 homework questions. They're sole duplicates in basically every case anyhow..

Comment: @ashleysmith The reason we're suggesting trees and such is because that's how we'd tell a colleague to solve the problem. You explicitly stated this wasn't a homework problem, and we trusted you (sort of). But it *is* homework. You never stated any requirements or restrictions in how the problem should be solved. What did you expect? We can't read your mind, and it's even *more* difficult to read your mind when you lie.

Comment: @ashleysmith And you might want to try asking a more-specific question on [javaranch](http://javaranch.com), which IMO is more beginner-friendly. You'll still be expected to show things like what you've tried to far and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a grammar and a parser to do this in a general way.  Something like [this](http://www.singsurf.org/djep/html/index.html).